# Proper method for making changes to a protected spreadsheet from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to work with a protected workbook (i have access to the password) with a VBA project (1 UserForm, 5 Class Modules, 1 Standard Module)

I'm really confused about how to properly work with protected sheets in VBA.

I've tried doing an

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect PWD
```

followed after a method call with

```
ActiveSheet.protect PWD
```

Also tried

```
ActiveSheet.protect PWD, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

from the Workbook_open sub

The issues is at random points its like the protection reverts to being protected and the parts of my VBA project that are making changes to the actual spreadsheet freak out.

If i pause the debugger go over and manually unprotect the sheet and hit continue things go off without a hitch

So what's going on here

Is it not enough to unprotect the sheet at the beginning of a method that calls other methods that make changes to the sheet and reportected it at the end?

or do I literally have to prefix and postfix

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect PWD
ActiveSheet.Protect PWD
```

around EVERY single line that changes the sheet data?

Because it seems like the protection cares nothing about anything my VBA project does internally ONLY when I try to do subsequent things with the worksheet

I can post code later today when I get home if its needed

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it not enough to unprotect the sheet at the beginning of a method that calls other methods that make changes to the sheet and reportected it at the end?*

This is why global state is such a pain in the neck. As far as your VBA project is concerned, sheet protection state is global. So if you do:

```
Public Sub Procedure1()
    Sheet1.Unprotect PWD
    Procedure2
    'do stuff on Sheet1
    Sheet1.Protect PWD
End Sub
```

If `Procedure2` re-protects `Sheet1` before it exits, then `Sheet1` is protected again when `Procedure1` resumes to `do stuff on Sheet1`, and as you're experiencing, it doesn't like it much.

So yes, you need to be sure that the sheet isn't protected before you try to modify it.

> *or do I literally have to prefix and postfix [...] around EVERY single line that changes the sheet data?*

You don't. I mean, you *do*, but you don't, *if you manage your global state in a sane way*. If anyone anywhere at any time can go in and re-protect the sheet you just unprotected, your *swear jar* can fill up rather quickly.

Similarly, `Application.Calculation` is global; yet if anyone anywhere can set it back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` after you carefully made it `xlCalculationManual` in an effort to "improve performance" (same goes for `Application.ScreenUpdating`), then you'll ultimately find yourself triggering recalculations *and introduce very noticeable lags instead*.

Global state is nice (hey I can access it from anywhere!), but also double-edged. If you don't structure things properly, global state quickly *spagghettifies* and becomes a tangled mess of inefficient back-and-forth toggles that you don't need, or want.

The solution is to set yourself up for success, and *layer* your code properly. Have all the sheet-protection-toggling code in one place, and constrain yourself to only ever invoke that logic from one single layer - everything underneath isn't concerned with sheet protection, it's none of its business. If the sheet it means to work with is protected, then **it's not its problem** - code in the upper layer has a bug.

In the above example, `Procedure2` would be layer 2, and it **shouldn't be allowed to toggle sheet protection at all**. Let `Procedure1` be responsible for that, and move the `do stuff on Sheet1` part to some new `Procedure3`, that 's just as carelessly assuming sheet protection is already handled.

You can even encapsulate the toggling in a class, e.g. `Sheet1Protection`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Sheet1.Unprotect PWD
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Sheet1.Protect PWD
End Sub
```

And now you can do this:

```
Public Sub Procedure1
    With New Sheet1Protection 'unprotects sheet1
        Procedure2
        Procedure3
    End With ' object terminates, sheet1 is protected again
End Sub
```

Notice that sheet protection is being toggled at the very last minute, when it's needed, and wraps all operations that need to run with the unprotected sheet.

With tooling such as [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (an OSS add-in project for the VBE, which I manage & contribute to) you can easily locate all the places where sheet protection is being toggled outside of `Sheet1Protection`, and remove them.